# jquery validation plugin ajax submit a form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I use jquery validation plugin to do validation in a bootstrap modal form, when i send the form ,the jquery validation plugin is working but ajax code will do two time and the form cannot send out.

bootstrap form

```
<form class="contact">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="topic" class="control-label ">topic</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="topic" />
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ruser" class="control-label "> ruser: </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ruser" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" readonly/>
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content" class="control-label ">content:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="3"></textarea>
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="submitcontact">ok</button>
</form>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            topic: {
                required: true
            },
            ruser: {
                required: true
            },
            content: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            topic: {
                required: 'enter topic'
            },
            ruser: {
                required: 'enter nuser'
            },
            content: {
                required: 'enter content'
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("ok!");
                    if (msg == 'ok') {
                        alert(msg);
                        location.reload()
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('#submitcontact').click(function () {
        $('form.contact').submit();
    })
});
```

How can i fix the problem?

The **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eoreedb/)**

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove this bit:

```
$('#submitcontact').click(function(){
     $('form.contact').submit();
})
```

Please see the example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8eoreedb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.valid()` method:

> Description: Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected elements are valid.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8eoreedb/5/)

```
$('#submitcontact').on('click', function() {
    if ($('form.contact').valid()) {
        // Form is valid
        $('form.contact').submit();
    }
});
```

Doc: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8eoreedb/4/